# Using Media Capture in .Net 4.5

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows-8

I'm trying to use this source code off of MSDN for capturing media off a webcam:
[Media capture using capture device sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Media-Capture-Sample-adf87622/).

The problem I'm having is every time I try to build it, it complains: 'the System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter does not contain a definition for  IsCompleted'.

I'm just getting familiar with the async features of 4.5, which I understand to be the root cause of this error, but I'm not sure how.

Couple notes: I'm running Windows 8.1, and I'm making a WPF app (not windows store), so I had to make some changes, such as the TargetPlatformVersion, the assembly references, etc.